# passing parameters from javascript function to batch file

Tags: javascript, html, batch-file

I am trying to create a html page for client from which he'll be able to start or stop a particular window service on any remote desktop. Total no. of services in scope are around 20. Rather than creating 20(start) + 20(stop) + 20(restart) batch file, i want to have 1 batch file with if else condition, I could pass parameter in javascript function. Code for html page is below :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>   
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
MyObject = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell")
function start()
{
MyObject.Run("\"E:\\start.bat\"");
}
function stop()
{
MyObject.Run("\"E:\\stop.bat\"");
}
function restart()
{
MyObject.Run("\"E:\\restart.bat\"");
}
</script>
<title>Our Company</title>
</head>
<body>
<table background-color:#f1f1c1; border="1" style="width:50%" align="center">
<tr>
<th style="text-align:center">Instance Name</th>
<th style="text-align:center">Accessible URL</th> 
<th style="text-align:center">Status</th>
<th style="text-align:center">Start</th>
<th style="text-align:center">Stop</th>
<th style="text-align:center">Restart</th>
</tr>
<tr height="70%">
<td style="text-align:center">netadds</td>
<td style="text-align:center">
<a href="http://localhost/">localhost:netadds</a></td> 
<td style="text-align:center">Running</td>
<td style="text-align:center"><button onclick="start()">Start</button></td>
<td style="text-align:center"><button onclick="stop()">Stop</button></td>
<td style="text-align:center"><button onclick="restart()">Restart</button>          </td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

and code in start.bat is :

```
@echo off
net start AMAPTestJetty8i0T1
if ERRORLEVEL 1 goto error
exit
:error
echo Could not start service
pause
```

Please suggest how can I apply if else statement in batch and pass parameter in start function.

Answer (score 1):

To pass parameters to your BAT file :

```
MyObject.Run("E:\start.bat The_parameter1 The_parameter2");
```

To get the parameters in your BAT File :

```
echo parameter 1 = %1
echo parameter 2 = %2
```

To make an `IF ELSE` test in a BAT

```
net start AMAPTestJetty8i0T1
if %ERRORLEVEL%==1 (goto error
    ) else (
 goto NoError)
```

Or using **Conditional command separator** :

```
net start AMAPTestJetty8i0T1 && goto NoError || goto Error
```

Comment: "redirection" might be a confusing term as you are using it; I'd call it "conditional command separator"...

Comment: For what are you using "Conditional command separator" ? To make a redirection.....

Comment: "redirection" is something like `echo text>file.log`; `&&` and `||` are totally different things...

Comment: Yes, it's a conditional redirection of the code and not of the output.