# Pass variable from JavaScript to Windows batch file

Tags: javascript, windows, batch-file, extendscript

Is it possible to create a variable in JavaScript and pass it to a batch file?
Just as a simple test echo a variable and move a file up a directory.

**JavaScript.js**

```
var s = "Gwen Stefani";
var myFile = "C:\\temp\\myfile.txt"
myBat.execute();
```

**myBat.bat**

```
echo s 
move myFile ..
```

An alternative is to create a string which is saved out as a batch file and then executed, but I was wondering if if it could be done directly.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32807609/passing-parameters-from-javascript-function-to-batch-file I think this answers the question.

Comment: yes, `> doit.bat 123` will set `%1` to `123` inside of doit.bat

Comment: What is the `mv` command you are using in the batch file? do you mean [`move`](http://ss64.com/nt/move.html) instead?

Comment: All the answer assume node.js or the browser environment. Are you some adobe application? Would be good to add this to your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use command line arguments (as you are using exec I suppose this is node.js):

```
var s = "Gwen Stefani";
var myFile = "C:\\temp\\myfile.txt"
const exec = require('child_process').exec;
const child = exec('cmd /c myBat.bat '+ myFile+' '+s,
    (error, stdout, stderr) => {
        console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
        console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
        if (error !== null) {
            console.log(`exec error: ${error}`);
        }
});
```

or for extendscript:

```
var s = "Gwen Stefani";
var myFile = "C:\\temp\\myfile.txt";
system.callSystem('cmd /c myBat.bat '+ myFile+' '+s');
```

and the bat file:

```
echo %2
move "%~1" ..
```

(mv is unix command but not from windows shell)